# jquery autocomplete not working after dynamically loading html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

im making a call to load function which dynamically loads a part of the jsp. after the load functionm call i notice that the autocomplete on a input box is not being responsive. it was fine earlier before the load function call. The load function replaced a a div with the given id and the autocomplete textbox already exists before the load call. the following is the code for my autocomplete. please help

```
$('.directoryAutoComplete').autocomplete({
    source : system.ctx+ '/autocomplete/people',
    focus : function() {
        return false;
    },
    select : persons.autocompleteSelected,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reattach the autocomplete after you dynamically load the new html.  When you swap out the html you've removed the autocomplete as well as the old html.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: whatever routine is responsible for swapping out the html you want to call that above snipped afterwards.  Just put the whole thing in after you do the swap.